# How Do I Incorporate Google Adsense Into My Product Pages

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.2, google-api

I realize there is one other question on this issue with no real answers only counter questions to the op that question is here

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79516/how-to-add-an-ad-from-adsense-to-my-magento

but I am specifying what page and I will be more attentive then the other op with follow ups.

google adsense is only a small snippet of code, but Im gonna be honest I understand all the blocks and page and phtml like I understand Cyrillic languages... I dont... not at all.

All I want to do is have it show up at the bottom of the page.  I think I managed to get it on the side (although i never saw any ads, probably due to it being my first day with adsense Im told) from this post

http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/how-do-i-get-adsense-ads-on-my-site-90103.html

althought that may have not worked as it should, but still it made a block reservation on the right side, but this was only on the home page, and not on the product pages.

I have a huge bounce rate on my product pages from google searches and want to captivate on this bounce rate.

Answer (score 2):

Well with that link you're on the right track. But in this case it's added to the right column and that's actually not in the Product view.

So it all depends on the place you want the Adsense snippet. For explanation sake I'll pick a spot but I suggest you read up on layout XML with [this article](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/) so you'll get a better understanding to move it around.

So let's create a static block called `adsense_code`. Now we'll add that to our `local.xml` in your template.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="cms/block" name="adsense_code">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>adsense_code</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

this doesn't actually shows it, in the `catalog/product/view.phtml` we can do that in 2 ways.

Normally we would use `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('adsense_code');?>` in the template somewhere to echo the HTML of the block.

But on the product view we can also append it to a generic block. Our layout XML would like like following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="cms/block" name="adsense_code">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>adsense_code</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom">
           <action method="append"><block>adsense_code</block></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Comment: i will try this first thing tomorrow... i appreciate the quick reply as i am sure others will as well, but just a side note.  is this something i am going to have permissions issues with, i know the update to 1.9.2.2 had a lot of permissions settings added and mandated for things to run

Comment: Hi @Chris ,  you shouldn't have any permission issues with that. That just applied to custom module with pad permission settings

Answer (score 0):

the way that i got it to show up alone and only in my product pages... well below the product info right before the footer was to include this in the local.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
        <catalog_product_view>
                <reference name="content">
                        <block type="cms/block" name="adsense_code">
                                <action method="setBlockId">
                                        <block_id>adsense_code</block_id>
                                </action>
                        </block>
                </reference>
                <reference name="content">
                        <action method="append">
                                <block>adsense_code</block>
                        </action>
                </reference>
        </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

and obviously include the adsense snippet into its cms block